# JFreeChart with JavaFX, when zoom in or zoom out, repaint works not well

Tags: javafx, jfreechart

I have a problem using JFreeChart with JavaFX. I wrote a small program here to help explain.

At first the graph likes this:

[image]

I use fullScreen function to display the JFreeChart Line Chart Demo 2. Here I use SwingNode, ChartPanel to embedded JFreeChart into JavaFX Panel.(Detail part will be included in code later)

Then I press ESC to exit fullScreen. Then it looks like this:

[image]

So far, it's as expected. Then I use mouse drag to enlarge the window. Here comes the problem, as the following picture.

[image]

Can you see that, seems like appear another graph. And I must click on the window, then everything will become good.So my question is: anyone knows why?
I wish the graph shows well even when I drag the window to enlarge, is there something I missed?

And here is my code:

```
package testxychart;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class TestXYChart extends Application {
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        SplitPane vSplitPane = new SplitPane();
        vSplitPane.getItems().add(this.creatChart1());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vSplitPane));
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private SwingNode creatChart1(){

        XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("First");
        series1.add(1.0, 1.0);
        series1.add(2.0, 4.0);
        series1.add(3.0, 3.0);
        series1.add(4.0, 5.0);
        series1.add(5.0, 5.0);
        series1.add(6.0, 7.0);
        series1.add(7.0, 7.0);
        series1.add(8.0, 8.0);
        XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Second");
        series2.add(1.0, 5.0);
        series2.add(2.0, 7.0);
        series2.add(3.0, 6.0);
        series2.add(4.0, 8.0);
        series2.add(5.0, 4.0);
        series2.add(6.0, 4.0);
        series2.add(7.0, 2.0);
        series2.add(8.0, 1.0);
        XYSeries series3 = new XYSeries("Third");
        series3.add(3.0, 4.0);
        series3.add(4.0, 3.0);
        series3.add(5.0, 2.0);
        series3.add(6.0, 3.0);
        series3.add(7.0, 6.0);
        series3.add(8.0, 3.0);
        series3.add(9.0, 4.0);
        series3.add(10.0, 3.0);
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series1);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);
        dataset.addSeries(series3);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Line Chart Demo 2", // chart title
                "X", // x axis label
                "Y", // y axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
        );
        ChartPanel chartPane = new ChartPanel(chart);
        SwingNode sNode = new SwingNode();
        sNode.setContent(chartPane);
        return sNode;
     }



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Thank you so much for any advice. 
I think, when I use several graphs in one JavaFX Panel, this will becomes a big problem.

Comment: Hi, anybody has any idea?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any solutions to this JFreeChart/SwingNode-JavaFx issue?